# my script has php mailer error

Tags: php, html

Could you guys help me with following problem:

[image]

my code:

```
<?php
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

if ($_POST['submit']) {

    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $error="<br/>- S'il vous plaît entrez votre nom";
    }
    if (!$_POST['email']) {
        $error.="<br/>- S'il vous plaît entrez votre email adresse";
    }
    if (!$_POST['message']) {
        $error.="<br/>- S'il vous plaît entrez le message";
    }
    if (!$_POST['check']) {
        $error.="<br/>- s'il vous plaît confirmer que vous êtes humain";
    }

    if ($error) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> <strong> oups, vous avez un erreur : </strong>'.$error.'</div>';
    } else {
        mail("1992rax@gmail.com", "contact message", "<br> Name: ".$_POST['name']."<br> Email: ".$_POST['email']."<br> Message: ".$_POST['message'],$headers);        

        $result='<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> merci votre message a été envoyer</div>';

    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

    <head>
      <title>fowaj project website</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8" >
      <meta name="author" content="oussama el badaoui" >
      <meta name="description" content="this is an website comunity gallery of images hummour">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >
      <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png">
      <!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"><![endif]-->

      <!-- Bootstrap main css -->
      <link href="layout/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <!-- custom css -->
      <link href="layout/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body> 
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
                  <img src="layout/images/logo.png" alt="fowaj project" />
              </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Accueil <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contacte</a></li>
                <li><a href="Privacy-policy.htm">Politique de confidentialité</a></li>
                <li><a href="term-and-conditions.htm">termes et conditions</a></li>
                <li><a href="about-us.htm"">à propose</a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                </form>
                  <li><a href="admin/index.php">Connexion</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>

        <section id="contact">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h1>contact formulaire </h1>   

                    <?php echo $result;?> 

                <p> envoyer votre message par cette formulaire</p>

                <form method="post" role="form">

                  <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="enter votre nome" value="<?php echo $_POST['name'];?>">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="enter votre email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email'];?>">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea name="message" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="enter votre message ..."><?php echo $_POST['message'];?></textarea>
                  </div>

                  <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="check"> je suis humain
                    </label>
                  </div>

                    <div align="center">
                       <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="envoyer le message" />
                    </div>

                </form>

              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </section>      


            <footer>
                <div class="list-group col-md-4">
                    <a class="list-group-item active">Catégories:</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Caricatures</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Cinéma et tv</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Politique</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item" href="#">enfants</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item" href="#">animaux</a>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group col-md-4">
                    <a class="list-group-item active">les Pages de site:</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item" href="contact.php">Contacter Nous</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item" href="Privacy-policy.htm">Politique de confidentialité</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item" href="term-and-conditions.htm">termes et conditions</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item" href="about-us.htm">à propose de Nous</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#regModal" >ajouter votre image</a>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group col-md-4">
                    <a class="list-group-item active">média sociaux:</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item" href="http://facebook.com/fowajproject" target="new">facebook</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item" href="http://twitter.com/fowajproject" target="new">twitter</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item" href="http://youtube.com/fowajproject" target="new">youtube</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item" href="http://plus.google.com/fowajprojetc" target="new">google plus</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 footer-info">
                    copyright © 2016 fowaj project made in morocco by oussama el badaoui
                </div>
            </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "i need help now please" X 4 - I would appreciate if you can show some patience, as this is not a paid support forum !! And you got the answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: If make any new question to SO, I kindly request to describe better your problem instead of writing "i need help now please" several times... Say you are new to a code language or desperately ask for help does not make your question better.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined $header!!! At the top of your file you have:

```
<?php
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

You are appending with `.=` something to a variable that doesn't exist!
Instead, simply define $headers with `=`:

```
<?php
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

That should do the trick.

You should add the code from the dropbox link you gave me in your first post.
You should try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']) {

    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $error = "<br/>- S'il vous plaît entrez votre nom";
    }
    if (!$_POST['email']) {
        $error = "<br/>- S'il vous plaît entrez votre email adresse";
    }
    if (!$_POST['message']) {
        $error = "<br/>- S'il vous plaît entrez le message";
    }
    if (!$_POST['check']) {
        $error = "<br/>- s'il vous plaît confirmer que vous êtes humain";
    }

    if ($error) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> <strong> oups, vous avez un erreur : </strong>'.$error.'</div>';
    } else {
        mail("1992rax@gmail.com", "contact message", "<br> Name: ".$_POST['name']."<br> Email: ".$_POST['email']."<br> Message: ".$_POST['message'],$headers);        

        $result ='<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> merci votre message a été envoyer</div>';

    }
}
```

Comment: If you find this answer helpful, please upvote/validate it, thanks!

Comment: the problem stile exist :

Comment: @Oussama You should at least try my proposal and give us the new error report.

Comment: ok this is the problem:

http://i.imgur.com/5XY2o3P.png

and this is my code:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/93458058/contact.php

Comment: That means that `$_POST['submit']` isn't defined. Is it a form that redirects to this page ? What should `$_POST['submit']` hold ?

Comment: Can you validate/upvote my answer for future use ? Thanks

Comment: i can't i have less then 15 in reputation

Comment: how can i validate  am new in stackoverflow.com ?

Comment: Click on the tick bellow ▲0▼ on top left of this post

Comment: anyone can validate an answer, no need for reputation points http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges